# Access Variant Options in Collection Template

Tags: shopify

I'm working on a shopify app, and I'm building a filter system to filter products by availability of variants from the collection page, i.e. color, size, etc.

I have the variants put into a hidden span tag on the collection page, but it always returns an info hash, instead of a variant name.

span tag:

```
<span>
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
       {{ variant }}
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

But instead of returning useful things like 'red', 'black', 'blue', it returns this:

```
<span>
  "#"
  <productvariantdrop:0x00000003dee880></productvariantdrop:0x00000003dee880>
</span>
```

Any one know whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple. {{variant}} is an object. Obviously of type **productvariantdrop**. If you want the variant options, you will have to dig deeper and expose them via the iterator on the options. See the docs for **variant** to tell you more. Example http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant and variant.options.

Answer (score 3):

use {{ variant.title }} to get option title like Red, Green etc
and {{ variant | json }} to print a complete dump